# 投稿後に自らが試したことについての追記において、タイトルの編集をどうするべきか

Tags: サポート

タイトル「○○という状況において、××」という質問を投稿したのですが、あとから○○という状況が関係ない可能性が高いということが分かりました。
本文には編集で追記すればよいと思うのですが、タイトルは、後から見た人が追えるように「○○(関係ない可能性大)という…」とするべきでしょうか、それとも可読性を重視して○○の部分を消してしまうべきでしょうか。

具体的には、[cmake、mingw-w64、msysの本体を名前が日本語のディレクトリの下にインストールしたときにcmakeが行えない](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/47727/cmake-mingw-w64-msys%e3%81%ae%e6%9c%ac%e4%bd%93%e3%82%92%e5%90%8d%e5%89%8d%e3%81%8c%e6%97%a5%e6%9c%ac%e8%aa%9e%e3%81%ae%e3%83%87%e3%82%a3%e3%83%ac%e3%82%af%e3%83%88%e3%83%aa%e3%81%ae%e4%b8%8b%e3%81%ab%e3%82%a4%e3%83%b3%e3%82%b9%e3%83%88%e3%83%bc%e3%83%ab%e3%81%97%e3%81%9f%e3%81%a8%e3%81%8d%e3%81%abcmake%e3%81%8c%e8%a1%8c%e3%81%88%e3%81%aa%e3%81%84) において、cmakeが行なえないことが、「各インストール先が日本語のディレクトリの下であること」に起因しないことが分かったのですが、タイトルはどう修正すべきでしょうか。

追記
とりあえずタイトルを変更せずに編集しました。

Answer (score 3):

該当の質問に関しては「cmakeの実行でエラーになる」が話の中心かと思うので、その部分が伝わる形であれば元タイトルから「日本語を含むディレクトリ以下で～」の説明は省いてしまっていいのではと私は思います。
(回答の参考になると思うので、本文の方には試行錯誤の結果は残しておいた方がよいでしょう)